# Where does XMLHttpRequest.send() send uploaded files?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I have a little problem with my website. I'm making a site for a friend of mine that allow her to upload her drawings on it. I use asynchronous upload thanks to the .send() method of an XMLHttpRequest object. Here is my JS script :

```
var f             = file;
var name          = f.name;
var filesize      = f.size;

xhr.addEventListener("load" , function(e){
        location.reload();
});

xhr.open("post", 'import.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
xhr.setRequestHeader('type', f.type);
xhr.setRequestHeader('filename', name);
xhr.setRequestHeader('path', '<?php echo $path ?>');
xhr.send(f);
```

And here's my PHP page where I save the uploaded file :

```
extract($_SERVER);
$file = $HTTP_FILENAME;
$newPath = $HTTP_PATH;
$extension = explode('.',$file);
$extension = $extension[1];

if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'zip'){

    exec('cd '.IMG_ROOT);
    $handle   = fopen($newPath.$file, "w+");
    /*
      Adding line after line the source file datas in the destination file
    */
    // Get the uploaded file
    $uploadedFile = fopen("php://input", "r+");

    if($uploadedFile)
    {
      while ($buffer = fgets($uploadedFile))
      {
        fwrite($handle, $buffer);
      }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    if($extension == 'zip'){
        $unzip = exec('which unzip');
        exec($unzip.' '.$newPath.$file);

        $rm = exec('which rm');
        exec('rm '.$newPath.$file);
    }
}
```

My problem is that this works perfectly fine when I test it in localhost but not online...
It seems that the file is never sent... Can anyone tell me if I did something wrong ? And/or redirect me to something that explains the send() method and where the file is sent ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't extract superglobals, escape your `exec` calls, and use PHP's [zip](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php) and [file deletion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) facilities. You also need to be careful about zip bombs.

Comment: Is that an answer for my problem or just few advices on programming ? Either case thank you, I will do that :) but I don't think this will correct my problem which is that I cannot retrieve the uploaded file I sent... But all my php variables contain the correct datas...  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your destination directory writable?